# List of user data in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Suppose I wanted to have a table of users for people who collected various rare video games. Further suppose I made a model for a list of video games that can be created and saved by those users. How would I save the list in the database.

For example, my thoughts are there would be a cell in the user table called game_list which is a comma separated list of game('s). The games being a separate table with static game data and statistics which the users can pick from to create their rare game list.

Is this the best way? BTW, I am using rails, in case of specific solutions. I know this question is rather general, but I have a hard time phrasing the question to google and this site to get the answer I am looking for. I'm quite new to web development (SQL and HTML5 parts mostly), but not programming (been programming for a long time).

Thank you!

Comment: You should have three tables:  `Users` for the users.  `VideoGames` for the video games, and a junction table `UsersVideoGames` that has foreign key references to the other two.  Comma separated lists are not a good idea in relational databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Each entry in the `UsersVideoGames` would tie a `user_id` and a `game_id` right? And each a single user could have multiple entries to that junction database right?

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship. One usually models this with a table for user information, a table for game information, and a table for each user-game relation:

```
create table user(
  user_id int primary key,
  user_name varchar(255));
create table game(
  game_id int primary key,
  game_name varchar(255));
create table user_game(
  user_id int not null references user(user_id),
  game_id int not null references video(video_id));

insert into user values (1, "ed"), (2, "bob");
insert into game values (1, "pacman"), (2, "poker");
insert into user_game values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2);

select user_name, game_name
from user
natural join user_game
natural join game;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b637/1

Answer (score 1):

A thing you could do is make a form, so the user can choose which games they wanna store. Then you take the games the user have selected and make a array.

Foreach game in the array you do a query to the table in your database which contains the game data, and you get the id and make a array. Then you use `var game_list = serialize($array)` in php (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), for example and update the user table with the variable you got from `serialize()`.

If you then wanna get the data and make it to a array again you should use `var game_list = unserialize($row)`.